# communicating with SAS datasets from R

Tags: r, sas

I have a bunch of datasets that are in SAS format.  I would like to avoid using SAS since I think R provides more than enough functionality for me.  Therefore, is there a package that would allow me to interact with the SAS datasets from R?  I have the SAS software installed but I would like to avoid coding things in multiple languages.

Comment: General reference for import/export format questions in R: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf

Comment: What kind of SAS format? `sas7bdat` or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you have SAS, you can use Frank Harrell's 'Hmisc' package which has `sas.get` and `sasxport.get` functions. It also has a bunch of utility functions: `label,sas.get`, `contents`,`describe`. For those without a SAS license, package 'foreign' has `read.ssd`, `lookup.xport`, and `read.xport`.

EDIT1: I will also mention that Anthony Joseph Damico recently announced a package to parse SAS INPUT code into read.fwf code. From its description file: " Using importation code designed for SAS users to read ASCII files into sas7bdat files, the SAScii package parses through the INPUT block of a (.sas) syntax file to design the parameters needed for a read.fwf() function call."

EDIT2: There is also a package by Matt Shotwell called 'sas7bdat' with `read.sas7bdat(file)` that describes its function as " Read SAS files in the sas7bdat data format."

Comment: `sas7bdat` is experimental. So experimental, in fact, that I've never managed to get it to work -- and I did try.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I hope you communicated with its author.

Comment: reading sas7bdat works fine for me, even without SAS installed. But I wonder whether there is an opportunity to read SAS source code without installing it. Not run the code, only read it.

Comment: Not being a SAS user (since 1999) I have little memory of what "SAS source code" formats would be. I always used text files for my SAS source, (SAS is after just seeing the world as a bunch of punch cards, right), but maybe PC-SAS has added some proprietary format.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, the [haven](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=haven) package can read and write sas7bdat and SAS xpt files.  This package is consistent with other import/export packages in the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

There is also a package called [libr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=libr) that simulates a SAS `libname()` function almost exactly. This package is part of a system of packages called [sassy](https://r-sassy.org/) that recreates many basic SAS concepts in R.

Comment: I wouldn't oversell the "write" part of that - it reads fairly well, but writing is (still) quite limited.  SAS7BDAT is a closed format, and anything outside of SAS should not be expected to interact perfectly - though Haven does a good job of reading, at least, for the most part.